# После изменения кода в vs code нужно сохранять файл чтобы изменения работали

Tags: visual-studio-code

Залезал в настройки, ничего не нашёл. По гуглу тоже

К примеру есть такой код:

```
    a_n = a1 + d * (n-1)
    s_n = ((a1 + a_n)/2) * n
    return(a_n, s_n)
print(summs(1, 4, 3))
```

Если я изменю значения, то чтобы эти значения работали мне нужно сохранять файл. Или если я изменю код, то чтобы эти изменения работали нужно сохранять файл и так даже при измене незначительной вещи

Comment: Какой язык? Хорошо бы тег поставить. Автосохрание в настройках попробуйте включить.